# Prove covariance between sufficient statistic and logarithm of base measure in exponential family is equal to zero

Tags: self-study, expected-value, covariance, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family

Exponential family form is
$$f_X(x) = h(x)\exp(\eta(\theta)\cdot T(x) - A(\theta))$$
I know
$$\operatorname{Cov}(T(x), \log(h(x)) = 0.$$
But how can I prove it?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Firstly, try to cite the resource(s) where you came across the result. Secondly, as @Zhanxiong noted, show your effort/approach to (dis) prove the result. And (this time I added) from next time, please add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false.  As a counterexample, let $f_X(x) = xe^{-x}, x > 0$ (i.e., Gamma(2, 1) distribution) so that $T(X) = X$ and $h(X) = X$.  Simulation shows that the covariance of $X$ and $\log(X)$ is around $1$:

```r
> x <- rgamma(100000, shape = 2, rate = 1)
> cov(log(x), x)
[1] 1.007776
```